# Using Python to read data and use it in an if statement

Tags: python

I have a Python script writing to a .txt file (temperature in C).  I am looking for a way to read this data and use it in an if statement.

The .txt file contains only the temp, ex. (20.0), and I know how to read the data and print it, but I cant use the data for some reason.

Comment: `I cant use the data for some reason` What do you mean by this exactly?

Comment: how are you trying to use it?

Comment: more details please. you are hiding something critical

Comment: post some code please

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: convert the line you have read from the file to the proper type (e.g. a `float`). Assuming you have read the temperature (e.g. with `ts = f.readline()`), you can do `tf = float(ts)`

Comment: I'm only guessing, but my first thought is that you're unaware the float `20.0` that you expect, is really the string `'20.0'` and you're having trouble comparing against it. I wouldn't have to guess if you'd just respond to all of us asking for clarification.

Comment: So i would open the file, read it to the point where if i said:
print(temp)
it would read "20.0",
but i cant use this in an IF statement.

Comment: I guess my issue is, I can get the data to print, just cant use it.  I would like to be able to say:
if temp >= 20:
        print("hot")

Comment: What do you *mean* by `cant use it`? What is preventing you from saying `if temp >= 20`?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you expect `20.0` to be read from file as a float. It doesn't work that way. When you read from a file everything is a string, so when you say:

```
temp = my_data_read_from_file
if temp >= 20.0:
    print("hot")
```

You're really saying:

```
if '20.0' >= 20.0:
    print("hot")
```

Strings and floats don't compare that way. To see what I mean try this:

```
>>> '0' > 10000
True
```

You need to cast the file input to a float for comparison:

```
temp = float(my_data_read_from_file)
if temp >= 20.0:
    print("hot")
```